# How can I change the default assigned ip address for docker containers?

Tags: docker

I've tried /etc/default/docker modification with " -b docker0=10.1.1.50/24"

but it doesnt work.

I would like like my docker containers to have 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.49 with a docker router of 10.1.1.50

Does anyone knows how?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Docker [Advanced networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) documentation. In particular, see [the `--bip` and `--fixed-cidr` options](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#docker0). You can specify the IP space available to containers using `--fixed-cidr`, and the docker bridge IP with `--bip`.

To get something close to what you have specified, you can use `--fixed-cidr=10.1.1.0/26 --bip=10.1.1.62`. In this configuration the containers will have addresses 10.1.1.1-10.1.1.61 available and the Docker bridge will use 10.1.1.62.